# method is not called from xhtml

Tags: jsf, jpa, jsf-2, jpa-2.0

Whenever I am clicking the h:commandButton,the method associated with the action is not called.`action="#{statusBean.update}"` is not working, the update is not being called.

1) Here is my xhtml page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>


    <h:form >   
    <p:dataList value="#{statusBean.statusList}" var="p">
    <h:outputText value="#{p.statusId}-#{p.statusmsg}"/><br/>
    <p:inputText value="#{statusBean.comment.comment}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="comment" action="#{statusBean.update}"></h:commandButton>
    </p:dataList>
    </h:form>





</h:body>
</html>
```

2)Here is my statusBean

```
package com.bean;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.entity.Album;
import com.entity.Comment;
import com.entity.Status;
import com.entity.User;

public class StatusBean {
    Comment comment;
    Status status;
    private EntityManager em;

    public Comment getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(Comment comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public StatusBean(){
        comment = new Comment();
        status=new Status();
        EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("FreeBird");
         em =emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public String save(){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
        status.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        System.out.println("status save called");
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(status);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return "success";
    }
    public List<Status> getStatusList(){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        User user=(User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.email='"+user.getEmail()+"'", Status.class);
              List<Status> results =query.getResultList();
              return results;

    }
    public String update(){
        System.out.println("Update Called...");
        //comment.setStatusId(Integer.parseInt(statusId));
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(comment);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        return "success";

    }
}
```

Comment: See this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426433/commandbutton-in-datalist-inside-tab-of-accordionpanel-is-it-posible-primefaces

I think you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `@ManagedBean` annotation for your class and a scope annotation, e.g.

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class StatusBean {
    ...
}
```

Comment: My Status Bean is request scoped. I have used facesconfig.xml to set the scope of the bean.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem then i used a4j:jsFunction and problem was solved

`<a4j:jsFunction name="goToupdate"
action="#{statusBean.update()}" 
</a4j:jsFunction>`

now your h:commandButton look like this

`<h:commandButton value="comment" onclick="goToupdate()"></h:commandButton>`

Answer (score 0):

use `<p:commandButton>` instead of `<h:commandButton>`

for eg.`<p:commandButton value="comment" action="#{statusBean.update}" process="@this" ></p:commandButton>`

and put your bean in view scope